# I want to add duplicate email address in mailchimp subscriber list

Tags: mailchimp

how can I add duplicate email address in mailchimp subscriber list, when existing subscriber try to subscribe twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add an email address once to a list. You can create a second list, but lists don't communicate with each other. If you decide you want to combine the information in both lists, you will have to follow MailChimp's instructions on how to merge lists. (http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/growth/ways-to-combine-lists-in-mailchimp)

It's probably best, though, unless you're sending completely unrelated emails to your lists, to use things like fields, groups, and segments to organize your subscribers. They have a pretty comprehensive page on these items here: http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists

Answer (score 0):

You actually can’t add an existing email address into a single list.